# Permission denied while starting HDF5 library on Python

Tags: python, hdf5

I'am working with Unix and I need to use HDF5 to store data. According to HDF5's guide, http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/quick.html#quick, one should start by creating a new file.

```
import h5py
import numpy as np
f = h5py.File("mytestfile.hdf5", "w")
```

However, as soon as I run this code I get a weird error.

```
IOError: Unable to create file (Unable to open file: name = 'mytestfile.hdf5', errno = 13, 
error message = 'permission denied', flags = 13, o_flags = 602)
```

I don't get the meaning of the error. Does someone know if I need specific permission to use this library ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like the libary is ok, but creating the file is a problem. Try using a full path to the file you want to create. Also worth to mention which os you are using.

Comment: Ahah you were right, it's just the full path. I did not even think it could be that easy. Thanks !